# How to edit (read and then write) a file with c++ filestreaming?

Tags: c++, filestream

For example, if I need to add a sentence to the end of a file. I have to first open the file (e.g. "a.txt"), by

`ofstream outfile.open("a.txt");`

But whenever I do this, I will overwrite the existing "a.txt" in the same directory. Is it possible to edit the file like first read and then write?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Look up `std::ios_base::app` and `std::ios_base::ate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to open the file in 'append' mode. Passing `ios::app` to the open method causes the file to be opened in append mode.

```
f.open("file.txt", ios::app);
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/openmode/ for other flags

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
std::ofstream outfile( "a.txt", std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::ate );
```

*Various references*:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/ofstream/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/open/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa277521(v=vs.60).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266859(v=vs.60).aspx